# WPML is blocking WP core update

Tags: multisite, updates, core, plugin-wpml

I am tryin to update the core of Wordpress to 6.2 from the site desktop for a company whose WPML contract has expired.

This is the error I get from WP:
"WPML String Translation is trying to write .mo files with translations in the folder:
/www/domains/digitalscreen.com.0/public/wp-content/languages/wpml

Apparently, this folder cannot be written to. This is preventing the translation of strings from appearing on the website.

To resolve this, please contact your hosting company and request that they grant write permission to this folder.

For more details, please see the WPML documentation on troubleshooting .mo file generation issues."

I have checked "/www/domains/digitalscreen.com.0/public/wp-content/languages/wpml" the folder's permissions and it is set to 755, so I guess it should allow writting.

My question is what solution is better to continue with the core update:

1. May I desactivate WPML plugins, then proceed again to core update? In which case, will I be able to enable WPML plugins back again?
2. Will manually upgrade of the core work?

Thanks for any help provided

Comment: The directory's permissions might be `755` but what user is the owner of that directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wanted to avoid manually installation I have tried changing the permissions of the folder and files inside /www/domains/digitalscreen.com.0/public/wp-content/languages/wpml,

but since my 1st option did not work, I had try the 2nd one:

I have finally uninstalled all plugins and manually installed the WP core.

For this process I have downloaded the files from wordpress.org, used Filezilla to first delete wp-admin and wp-includes files, then uploaded the whole files in wp-content (overwriting all files), I have overwritten index.php file and finally uploaded the new wp-admin & wp-includes files from WP 6.2.

After that I have reinstalled all the pluggins, activated them one by one and… voilà! The page is doing well again!